# mmagic video super resulotion error about step_counter

Tags: python, video, deep-learning, artificial-intelligence, video-processing

I tried all of the following models
'''
'edvr'
'tdan'
'basicvsr'
'iconvsr'
'basicvsr_pp'
'real_basicvsr'
'''
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/agHlC.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JBn6Z.png)
Is RTX3090 really not enough memory , The key is that the video I input is about 500kb

Make the code work And try to input a larger video and try the results of all models